# Method to getComponent implements interface. Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types, interface, casting

I need method that can find component implements interface T.
I have this method but i does not work correctly. It should work like TryGetComponent(out Interface interface). Can you help?

```
public T RaycastFindComponent<T>(T targetType) where T : Type
{
    RaycastHit2D[] raycastHits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(_mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), new Vector2());
    foreach (RaycastHit2D raycastHit in raycastHits)
    {
        foreach (MonoBehaviour component in raycastHit.transform.GetComponents(typeof(MonoBehaviour)))
        {
            Type componentType = component.GetType();
            Debug.Log($"GetComponent = {componentType is T}"); //true
            if (componentType is T)
            {
                return component as T; //null but (componentType is T = true)
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It works if I use concrete Interface:

```
public Interface RaycastFindComponent()
{
    RaycastHit2D[] raycastHits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(_mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), new Vector2());
    foreach (RaycastHit2D raycastHit in raycastHits)
    {
        foreach (MonoBehaviour component in raycastHit.transform.GetComponents(typeof(Interface)))
        {
            Type componentType = component.GetType();
            Debug.Log($"GetComponent = {componentType is Interface}"); //true
            if (componentType is T)
            {
                return component as Interface; //(Interface)component
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to return a class of type `T` however the `T` constraint is defined as `Type`:

```
public T RaycastFindComponent<T>(T targetType) where T : Type
```

...is equivalent to:

```
public Type RaycastFindComponent(Type targetType)
```

...which isn't what you want.

It should read (note we don't need the parameter anymore):

```
public T RaycastFindComponent<T>() where T : Component, IMyInterface // NEW
{
    var targetType = typeof(T); // <--- NEW

    RaycastHit2D[] raycastHits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(_mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), new Vector2());
    foreach (RaycastHit2D raycastHit in raycastHits)
    {
        foreach (MonoBehaviour component in raycastHit.transform.GetComponents(targetType))
        {
            if (component is T)
            {
                return component as T; 
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You were essentially trying to cast `Type` to say `IMyInterface` which is *apples and oranges* and thus fails.

Comment: I understand. But I want to pass the interface type to be found. In your example, the interface is already written in the method signature.

Comment: `T` will be the _concrete_ class or _interface_ you are looking for.  e.g. `IMyInterface`.  The `where` constraint simply limits _which_ types can be used.  i.e. _it must be a `Component`, implement the interface `IMyInterface ` or derived_.  If you will be looking for interfaces always then you can drop the `Component` in the `where` constraint.

Comment: public interface Interface {}

The call should look like this:
_raycastHandler.RaycastFindComponent<Interface>();

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: But IDE throws an exception:

The type 'Interface' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'RaycastHandler.RaycastFindComponent<T>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Interface' to 'UnityEngine.Component'.

Comment: As mentioned you will need to drop the `Component` in the `where T : Component, IMyInterface` and just have `where T : IMyInterface`.  As a rule, it is generally better to look for the implemention object via _class_ rather than interface since classes represent _is a_ relationship whilst _interfaces_ are a _can do_.  Don't treat interfaces like _abstract classes_.  Interfaces may not be a 1:1 to the class that implements it.  If you do that then you use the `where T : Component, IMyInterface` which better represents the intent.

Answer (score 0):

> It should work like TryGetComponent(out Interface interface)

So first of all you want to pass in the type into the generic, not additionally an instance of it as a parameter!

Then secondly in order to really make it work like `TryGetComponent`

- You want to use an `out` parameter and return `bool`
- Why not actually use `TryGetComponent` which **does** support interfaces

so something like e.g.

```
public bool RaycastFindComponent<T>(out T result) where T : class
{
    var raycastHits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(_mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), new Vector2());

    foreach (RaycastHit2D raycastHit in raycastHits)
    {
        if (raycastHit.transform.TryGetComponent<T>(out result))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    result = default;
    return false;
}
```

The constraint `class` also includes interfaces since they are also reference-type so this can (just like Unity's `GetComponent` / `TryGetComponent`) take any class or interface as the generic type parameter.

```
if(RaycastFindComponent<ISomeInterface>(out var instance))
{
    Debug.Log("You hit {instance}", instance);
}
```

of course you could constrain it further down if needed, but I would start with the most generic and re-usable way and then you can still make more constrained versions of it